# APIM Developer Portal Sample Production Sites

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone know of instances where APIM developer Portal is being used in Production ?

For APIGEE I could see this link

https://devportalawards.org/

Do we have something similar to this for APIM developer portal

Answer (score 0):

WOW (Weather Observations Website) uses Azure's API Management https://mowowprod.portal.azure-api.net/documentation/how-to-connect-to-wow-api

Here are some other companies that use the APIM developer portal. https://idatalabs.com/tech/products/azure-api-management

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your own developer portal link on APIM instance. Please refer the image.

But you can't find the developer portals of others in one single place.
Below link will show you the customer list of Azure APIM,
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/case-studies/?service=api-management[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5ve3.png)

Thanks,
Infaaz